# How to represent this mongodb collection's row into cassandra supercolumnfamily/columnfamily

Tags: cassandra

i'm new in Cassandra.

I worked for a project using mongodb and i find it very simple to learn coming from different year using RDBMS.

At work now i need to learn cassandra , that is column oriented instead mongodb document oriented.

I read about cassandra and my mind is still document oriented.

I need to represent a very generic mongodb row possible schema like this into a cassandra supercolumnfamily/columfamily:

```
{
    "_id"  : ObjectId("mongodb-autogenerated-id"),
    key1   : "value1",
    key2   : "value2",
    ...
    keyN   : "valueN",
    keyN+1 : [{
                //array or object or value
             },{
                //array or object or value
             },
             ...
             {
                //array or object or value
             }],
    ...
    keyN+M : //array or object or value
}
```

Can someone explain me a little bit the real difference from columnfamily and supercolumnfamily just not with simple example but with a real example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supercolumns are deprecated due to performance reasons (and not only).
In old data models a CF could be of the Column type or SuperColumn type.
A SuperColumn is nothing more than a collection of columns identified by a key.

So, representing data using json

**CF DATA**

```
{ 
  "RowKey": {"col1":"col1_val", "col2":"col2_val", .... "colX":"colX_val" }
}
```

In java it would have been:

```
Map<String, Map<String, T>>
```

**SCF DATA**

```
    { 
      "RowKey": { 
           "sc1_key": {"col1":"col1_val", "col2":"col2_val", .... "colX":"colX_val" },
           "sc2_key": {"col1":"col1_val", "col2":"col2_val", .... "colX":"colX_val" },
           ...
           "scX_key": {"col1":"col1_val", "col2":"col2_val", .... "colX":"colX_val" },
    }
```

In java it would have been:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, T>>
```

But SCF used to drive to bad data models and, even if you needed a small subset of columns the whole super column had to be deserialized. Now SuperColumns have been replaced by "wide rows", and you can get them using composite primary keys.

I know very little of MongoDB, nothing more than 10 minutes gaming with it.
AFA your document in mongo, if I'm not wrong, you can perform any query with any key in your document, you can combine them with logical operators and so on.

In cassandra this is not possible, the best thing you can do is to work at a "query oriented data model", write all possible queries you perform on your DB and model yours data on this basis.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701494/sql-to-key-value/24707197#24707197) post you can find couple of tips and useful links for data modelling

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: so you think is better to design again my model in order to have a keyspace in cassandra using cf?

Comment: Definitely ... You should analyze all the queries you perform on your data in order to know how to model your data. The more queries the more will be the tables in your keyspace.

Comment: Newer model design could introduce multiple cf. Do you think is a good practice or is more like rdbms?

Comment: Having denormalization and multiple cf is the norm. eg: I have an application storing comments made by users on companies. Companies are located in different cities and I have to perform query like "get all user comments", "get all comments for this company", "get all comments made to companies in this city". Each query should return time-sorted comments. In my schema does not exists a COMMENTS table, I have 3 TABLES USER_COMMENTS, COMPANY_COMMENTS, CITY_COMMENTS, each one to answer a specific query. HTH, Carlo

Comment: ok! Understood!!! I need to design queries and after the model! Thanks Carlo!!! :)

Comment: So in cassandra our disk space will blow out 3 time faster than MongoDB given you have 3 queries to run on comments as each comment will be in 3 tables? Updates will be 3 times slower as now we have to update in 3 tables vs just one doc in MongoDB? Please clarify, I am planning to migrate from MongoDB to Cassandra